# 64bit Read Order on a 32bit RISC-V

Tags: gcc, riscv

I am trying to read a 64bit device register with a 32bit RISC-V MCU.

Here is my code

```c
uint64_t rd64(uint32_t addr){
    return *((volatile uint64_t *)(addr));
}

main(){
    ....
    uint64_t dataA = rd64(addrA);
    uint64_t dataB = rd64(addrB);
}
```

and I got the asm code with gcc

```
lw t5, 1234(a0) // Lower 32bit first
lw t6, 1238(a0)
lw a1, 1308(a0) // High 32bit first
lw a0, 1304(a0)
```

It seems gcc split the 64bit read into two 32bit read, but there is no guarantee which 32bit word come out first. This makes my device no happy.

Is there anyway to constrain gcc output with lower 32bit word come out first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cast your `uint64_t*` to a `volatile uint32_t[2]`, and read in the order you want. (or use a `volatile uint32_t*`, same idea)